# Не работает время (спецэффекта) в jQuery

Tags: jquery

Не понимаю, вроде все правильно сделал, все подключил, эффект работает, а время не хочет (спецэффекта).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.close_userbar').click(function () {
            $('.for_not_logged').hide('explode', 5000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Все, не надо, спс, разобрался. Просто надо было UI обновить.

Comment: А ответ то принять все равно надо

Answer (score 1):

`explode` - это в самом деле эффект из Jquery UI. В стандартном наборе jquery такого нету.

Answer (score 0):

А jQuery-UI подключен?